# How to create subject ( rx.js) with 2 parameters?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-components, subject

I am using service with subject as communication service for components in my angular2 application.

Calling method:

```
this.notification.create('test');
```

Service:

```
export class NotificationService {
  private static notificationSource = new Subject<any>()

  notiCreated$ = NotificationService.notificationSource.asObservable();

  create(message) {
    NotificationService.notificationSource.next(message);
  }
}
```

Called function:

```
  this.subscription = notification.notiCreated$.subscribe(
    data => {
       console.log(data);
       this.createNotification(data, 'warning');
  });
```

But I want to pass 2 params. And I got errors.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since the api for `next` is `next(value: T): void`, it can only take one parameter.
Ref: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscriber.js~Subscriber.html

As a workaround you can group the messages inside an object:

```
this.notification.create({message1:'test', message2:'test2'});
```

and when you consume, just select the message you need:

```
 this.subscription = notification.notiCreated$.subscribe(
    data => {
       console.log(data.message1, data.message2);
       this.createNotification(data.message1, 'warning');
  });
```

Comment: Is it impossible to do it with 2 param?

Comment: @MaxKarpovets No because the api for `next` is `next(value: T): void;` so it only takes 1 parameter.

Comment: You really helps me. Thanks